# Как кастомизировать шаблон Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Я нашел и просмотрел видео курсы они все однотипны. Далее их смотреть бесполезно. Дальше в изучении WP я застрял. Я не понимаю как кастомизировать тему?

Давайте по порядку:

1. Верстаю шаблон;
2. Беру стартовый шаблон для WP underscores.me
3. Вхожу в режим ступора потому что не могу понять как кастомизировать тему

Допустим у меня есть слайдер или несколько на проекте (owl-csrousel), а как его подключить так чтобы можно было с админки менять там слайды, а если на слайде есть текст с кнопкой? Как это подключить чтобы можно было с админки менять.

А если есть галерея. Как там менять картинки?

Возможно заказчик захочет еще что-то поменять. Какой-то текст он захочет редактировать.

Может быт я неправильно гуглю, но я ничего не могу понять.

Answer (score 1):

Как подключить owl-carousel?

Никак. Такого готового функционала в WordPress нет. Да и в других cms тоже нет. Разработчики плагинов слайдеров для WordPress (LayerSlider, Revolution Slider) пишут внушительное количество кода, который подхватывается в админке. Этот код и позволяет создавать собственные слайдеры.

Я бы посоветовал поставить на ваш сайт готовый плагин слайдера. Их очень много, на любой вкус. Те два, что я привел выше - платные и, пожалуй, самые мощные.

Если все же хочется создать страницу настроек своей темы в админке, то начните читать [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html). Это очень неплохое руководство на русском языке.

P.S. И лучше перестаньте пользоваться underscores.me - это примитив, на котором вы ничему не научитесь. Берите бесплатную тему WordPress, хоть twentyseventeen, или другую понравившуюся из репозитория, создавайте ее [дочернюю тему](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html) (обязательно) и правьте ее. Это путь к созданию правильного, надежного и адаптивного сайта.